# Can we create aws cognito userpool authentication with amplify for react native(without expo)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-userpools

They have mentioned two methods in documentation,

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-get-jwt-token-when-using-amplify-to-get-federated-users-login

So according to this userpool can be used with social login when we use hosted ui, using the same function Auth.federatedSignIn()

When i try this example (the example above #note for expo users),
https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#a-note-for-expo-users
it gives error - cognito.urlOpener is undefined.
But i found here the solution - update aws amplify libraries

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3000#issuecomment-479880086

current library versions - aws-amplify - 1.1.24-unstable.0
, aws amplify react native - 2.1.9

But when i update these app doesnt work - it gives error `undefined variable Symbol`

Someone please let me know whether we can use cognito userpool for react native apps with aws amplify social login.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try **amazon-cognito-identity-js** npm package, Which is easy to understand and implement.

Below is the link,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js

Comment: But this library has no methods to implement social login with cognito userpool. This has only social login with Identity pool.

Comment: Yes, @DinukaSalwathura social login method not there! it only manages the Cognito related method.